# Spring Android - POST Request - URL Encoded Params from Class Object

Tags: java, android, http-post, spring-android

I am trying to **send some key-value pairs in Android Spring POST Request**.It works correctly , if I am using a

`MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();`

for that. **Is there any way to avoid MultiValueMap & directly send the Class Object as Request**.

One solution found is using Reflection , like the following

```
for (Field field:objAuth.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    map.add(field.getName(),field.get(objAuth)+"");
                }
```

---

Code Snippet

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());


        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        Authenticate objAuth = new Authenticate();
        objAuth.setUserId("1");
        objAuth.setType("Type");
        objAuth.setoAuthToken("00112233");
        objAuth.setResponseCode("9689");
        objAuth.setResponseMessage("Last Message");

        /**
         * Using Reflection
         */
        for (Field field:objAuth.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
            field.setAccessible(true);
            map.add(field.getName(),field.get(objAuth)+"");
        }

        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(map , requestHeaders);

        String response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://posttestserver.com/post.php",requestEntity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting a media type of `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` with `FormHttpMessageConverter`, you must use a  `MultiValueMap`, as seen [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android/blob/master/spring-android-rest-template/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.java#L142-L144). Alternatively, if you want to post JSON, Jackson is used internally to convert any object class to JSON output. Spring uses message converters to determine how to read/write objects, and which types are compatible with which media types.