# How can we post dynamic json values in Retrofit

Tags: android

I am developing an e-commerce android application. am stuck in a situation, i don't know how to handle the situation. That is,

How can i post dynamic json values in Retrofit. For example

```
{
"type":"1",
"typeId":"10",
"userId":"15",
"filters":{
  "price":"from-to",
  "attribute_code":"values",
  "...":"....",
  "...":"...."
  }
}
```

in this the "filter" is another object in the main json. the values in "filter" json is dynamic like sometime it may have "price", "size" or sometimes it may have "price" only or some times it may have "price","size","offers" etc..
How can we handle this circumstance..

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220390/spring-android-post-request-url-encoded-params-from-class-object

Comment: sorry @Don, i didn't get clarity from your link.